# Enable google or any other font on server side rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have a server side rendering active on my page. However what I dont really like, is when the server side is active, the font is not loaded yet and it doesnt look that good.

But when the client side is loaded, you can see a font change and the items on the site are moving (because the loaded font is little bit bigger than the default font).

My question - if Im using `Lato` font from Google, how can I turn it on on server side? So it is also `Lato` on server side rendered?

Comment: are you using in-storage google font or external-storage google font?

Comment: @FahimUddin im importing it from google server

Comment: Try it downloading to your server, because your server should render it in it's methods.